# Creating a Multidimensional form from a JS dictionary

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to create a form to post data directly to an API. In Javascript the dictionary looks like:

```
  {
      "Data": {
          "Details": {
              "name": bob,
              "date": today
          },
         "number": 1
      }
  };
```

Is there any way to write this data into an HTML form that can be posted directly to the API?

Thanks

Comment: What is "the API"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long your API server accept extended form data syntax, you can do:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/your-endpoint">
   <input name="Details.name" value="bob" type="hidden" />
   <input name="Details.date" value="today" type="hidden" />
   <input name="number" value="1" type="hidden" />
   <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

The server will parse it as the object you mentioned, as long it supports the extended syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is your example html

```
<input id="name" type="text" value="initial value"/>
```

This would be your js code:

```
myobj = {
  "Data": {
      "Details": {
          "name": "bob",
          "date": "today"
      },
     "number": 1
  }
};
// write the value into the form elements
document.getElementById("name").value = myobj.Data.Details.name;
```

Try it with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/98d3ar28/